# The Joomla component "Advanced Module Manager" does not work with j2store. How to do?

Tags: php, module, joomla

Hi after hours and hours of trying I found that the component doesn't work with J2STORE.
The author says exactly: "Advanced Module Manager is compatible with it though. Just no a ready-to-use select option for it.
You can write a php assignment to check whatever you need.
See: https://regularlabs.com/extensions/advancedmodulemanager/faqs#i-want-to-assign-my-module-to-something-not-available-in-the-assignments "

Could anyone be able to explain to me more clearly how to activate this feature?

Thanks a lot to those who will help me

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow! You're more likely to get a helpful response if you describe what you've already tried, and can give a more precise description of what exactly isn't working, with a relevant snippet of your code.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment yet: I would recommend, that ask this in the Joomla! community: https://joomla.stackexchange.com/ or it can be moved there.

At the other hand would be a more precise question good. I banned for asking question, because of questions like this ...